# Retrieve previous and next rows in a table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html-table, row

I am using ASP.NET to create a page with a GridView that is very editable for the end user. Basically, all rows contain TextBoxes (instead of static text) which the user can edit whenever he wants. No postback occurs ever, except when he clicks the Save button on the bottom of the page. Then, I loop through each row in the grid, retrieve the values in the controls in each row and save them back to the database.

I am now trying to implement swapping two rows (to move a row up or down) in Javascript, and for that I need some way to retrieve the previous and next rows in a table.

At the moment my GridView contains a HiddenField as the first column, which contains the unique Id of the data item (I need this to store it back to the database of course). For other purposes (deleting a row) I have figured out how to retrieve this Id, which is this:

```
var itemHf = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(':input');
```

There's so many 'parent' calls because this happens in the click event of an Image, which is inside a LinkButton, which is inside the last column of my grid. So the first parent is the LinkButton, the next is the table cell, and finally the table row. Then, I suppose the    `find(':input')` function returns the first input element in this row (which in my case is the hidden field that contains the id).

So, using the same method I can get the *current* row:

```
var row = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
```

But how do I get the previous and next rows?

Also, once I have those rows, I will need to retrieve values from more input elements. I know I can find the first one using `find(':input')`, but how do I find the second and the third input elements in this table row?

EDIT
I don't have any html at this time but here is the ASP.NET markup for the grid:

```
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            onrowcommand="grid_RowCommand" onrowdeleting="grid_RowDeleting">
            <Columns>

                <!-- Move Up button -->
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="return false;">
                            <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Images/moveUp.png" AlternateText="moveUp" runat="server" CssClass="moveUp" ID="moveUp" />
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <!-- Move Down button -->
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="return false;">
                            <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Images/moveDown.png" AlternateText="moveDown" runat="server" CssClass="moveDown" ID="moveDown" />
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <!-- ID Hidden Field -->
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <!-- Name textbox field -->
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Naam">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="200px" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <!-- Price textbox field -->
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Prijs">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="50px" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <!-- Delete button -->
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="return false;">
                            <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" AlternateText="delete" runat="server" CssClass="delete" ID="delete" />
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And here is an example of the jQuery I'm using:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('table td img.delete').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).closest('tr').find(':input').val();
            alert(id);
        });
    });
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you'd post some corresponding HTML...

Comment: @Tomm I posted the ASP.NET (don't have access to rendered html right now) and how I'm using the jQuery. Hope it helps. I've now managed to get the next and previous rows, but now I also need to retrieve the next input elements on that row. I'm only finding the first one but there's two more after that (not in the same column of course, as you can see from the asp.net, so I guess I have to search starting 'one parent up'?)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can access the row by doing this:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
```

Now that you have the row, you can get the next/pre row by doing this:

```
var next = row.next();
var prev = row.prev();
```

To switch the rows around, you can use `.detach()` and `.appendTo()`

Comment: Thanks, I managed to retrieve the next and previous rows now. I can also move them using detach and attach (although they don't seem to switch around, one row seems to move up two places, the other seems to move down a few places, but that's probably my error). However, the rows move only client side; when I iterate the Rows collection of the GridView on the server side later, it returns them in the original order, so it also saves them in the original order.

Comment: If I could swap around the actual values in the inputs (beside the Id hidden field there's two textboxes), then I think they would be saved in their new order. For that, I also need to be able to find the next inputs. I am using `find(':input')` to find the first input, but how do I find the next one? I've had no luck using `next()` in this case, I tried several variations like `row.find(':input').next()` or `row.find(':input').parent().next(':input')` but no luck...

Comment: Ah, nice; you got it solved.  Did you end up switching the individual values, or were you able to track the row order by reading the row id on postback?

Comment: When I swapped the rows around using detach and appendTo, they did not swap around in the grid.Rows collection on the server after postback, so I couldn't detect moved rows that way. What I ended up doing was adding another hidden field column where I store the SortId of the data item, and I swap those around. When loading the data I just sort by SortId and that's all there's to it.

Comment: You don't need to detach an HTML element if you're just going to append it again.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. Once I got a row (either the current row or the previous row), I can find the first input element using the same format as before. Then I can find the closest cell ('td'), call next() on that and then find the first input element again:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
var idInput = row.find(':input');
var nextInput = idInput.closest('td').next('td').find(':input');
```

There might be a better way, but this works so I'm happy with it for now.

Thanks for your help, for some reason I can never quite grasp the concepts of jQuery...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your post `var row = $(this).parent().parent().parent();` could be replaced with

```
var row = $(this).parents("tr");
```

Furthermore `var itemHf = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(':input');` would probably better be expressed as

```
var itemHf = $(this).parents('tr').find('input:first');
```

So, to get the previous row you would use

```
var prevHf=$(this).parents('tr').prev().find('input:first');
```

and the next row would be

```
var nextHf=$(this).parents('tr').next().find('input:first');
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess `find('input:first')` explicitly only returns the first input element. How do I get to the second and third elements?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it! Your answer was good too by the way but I can only mark one as the accepted answer, sorry!