# Trying to delete two rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to delete two table rows at the same time in a dynamic table, but I'm having trouble deleting multiple rows at the same time. I have a table which displays text and a delete button in one tr and other related text in the next tr immediately after it. When I press the delete button on the first row, the row gets deleted but the one after it does not get removed. I have tried to get the value/address of the next row using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976137/retrieve-previous-and-next-rows-in-a-table-using-jquery) but it does not seem to be working for me.

**Fiddle in the works:** http://jsfiddle.net/DLqLW/3/

The button for deleting the row is coded this way:

```
<input type="button" id="<?php echo $str; ?>" class="button-add" name="butcli" value="-" onClick="deleteRow(this)"></input>
```

and the function that it calls is:

```
function deleteRow(el) {

                            while (el.parentNode && el.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'tr') {
                                el = el.parentNode;
                            }
                            if (el.parentNode && el.parentNode.rows.length > 1) {
                                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
                            }
                        }
```

I'm struggling with how to delete the next row after it. If anyone could provide some help, that would be great!

Comment: HTML of table? Fiddle perhaps?

Comment: Trying to get a fiddle up but currently I'm having some issues there too.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DLqLW/3/ I've created a fiddle but the javascript is not working, what's supposed to happen is that if you click the minus button on any of the rows containing them, the row right below it should be removed too.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work because it needs the function declared in `<head>` as you will see in mine: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/DLqLW/5/ -- Also, it does need to be parentNode.rows.length > 0 as @MazeHatter said.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9Zv83/ updated fiddle; now that the fiddle is working, what I'm trying to accomplish is that if for example I deleted the row containing the number 2, the row below it should be deleted too. I tried the nextSibling function faster mentioned, but it does not yield any results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Jquery this is working

```
function deleteRow(el) {
   var tr = $(el).closest('tr');
        tr.css("background-color","#FF3700");
        tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
            tr.remove();
        });
    var tr2 = $(tr).closest('tr').next();
        tr2.css("background-color","#FF3700");
        tr2.fadeOut(400, function(){
            tr.remove();
        });
}
```

Looks pretty swanky too I used your jfiddle with jQuery 2.02

Comment: But they didn't specify not using it either

Comment: using jQuery for a row removal if the OP didn't specify it, doesn't qualify as an answer in my opinion. it's an environment and theory change, not a solution *as-asked*.

Comment: Well lucky you have nothing to do with deciding if it answers the OP's question then. Since my example is possibly the only one working it has a better chance then most. If there are constraints like no jQuery it would be mentioned in the question otherwise it wouldn't be a valid question at all

Answer (score 0):

Do you have just two rows?

You are testing:

```
parentNode.rows.length > 1
```

If you have only two rows, it will not delete the second row.

Change it to:

```
parentNode.rows.length > 0
```

Comment: I have more than just 2 rows, the code >1 is supposed to specify the minimum number of rows that should be left in the table when a user is deleting rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_navigate.asp

```
function get_nextSibling(n)
{
y=n.nextSibling;
while (y.nodeType!=1)
  {
  y=y.nextSibling;
  }
return y;
}
```

Comment: I outputted the value of y and it gives me [object Text]. I've tried using y.parentNode.removeChild(y); but it's not working. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

### Alternate (simpler?) approach: Use a `<div>` rather than a sibling `<tr>`

A different approach, to keep it simple, avoid jQuery, and avoid `nextSibling` and related problems:

- **Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/9Zv83/3/

...using this HTML approach:

```
<tr>
    <td>1
        <div>this row should be deleted if the one above is removed.</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" id="<?php echo $str; ?>" class="button-add" name="butcli" value="-" onClick="javascript:deleteRow(this)"></input>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Also, your existing version relies on a `<tr>` which is short one cell. If you add `colspan=2` to your sibling row, then the formatting is thrown off too... hence this approach I am proposing.