# Use JQuery to Unhide Table Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table containing Employee Names. I would like to add a hidden row after each row that contained contact information for that particular employee. I would like to use JQuery to do a slideDown animation that reveals that information. 
If I was using Javascript, I would do something like name the TR element with an ID such as "employee-xx" and the hidden line as "hidden-xx" where xx is the employeeid. I would do an onClick event that called a function(using the employeeid as a parameter) to hide or unhide the line. As I am just starting JQuery, I don't know how to code this elegantly. I would like to tell it "When you click a visible line in the table, slideDown the invisible line below it", but don't know how to do that. If I use the ID of the row, how do I access the ID via JQuery? I know it's probably simple, but I am stuck.

Thank you,
John

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_siblings.asp

```
var clickhandler = function(e) {
  $(e.target).next().show();
}
```

btw, this has been answered on here before.

[Retrieve previous and next rows in a table using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976137/retrieve-previous-and-next-rows-in-a-table-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Fixed a derpy mistake with missing class name. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/ava0paq7/) has been updated.

I think this is what you want? Clicking on a row with a name causes the hidden row underneath to slide down. Click again to retract.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="show">
        <td>Bob Robertson</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hide">
        <td>
            <div>(555)123-4567</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="show">
        <td>Richard Johnson</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hide">
        <td>
            <div>(000)000-0000</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('.hide').toggle().find('div').slideToggle();

$('.show').on('click', function () {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (next.css('display') == 'none') {
        next.toggle();
        next.find('div').slideToggle();
    } else {
        next.find('div').slideToggle(function () {
            next.toggle();
        });
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/ava0paq7/).

Comment: Thank you...the TR for the name should be class "show" right?

Comment: @JohnJohnson Yes haha. I must have messed up somehow. Fixed now.