# Javascript: Need form cells to match

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript here is my situation. Below you will see that I am working with.

[image: my table]

This is what I need to have happen:

If row 2 and row 1 of pump are the same value I need row 2 of the SN# to automatically copy the number from row 1 of SN #.

How can I do this? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is a bit vague. Best would be if you post a minimal working example of your code and what you already tried. One rather simple solution would be to use jQuery and especially the .text() function (see https://api.jquery.com/text/) which you can use to get text (from the first cells) and set text in the third column.

Comment: Agree with Johannes, more detail would be helpful, a minimal example would be useful but also more detail about the data involved would be useful, because this looks more like a data problem - you may be able to fix this by fixing the data, or by modifying a database query if a database is used? You can certainly do this in JQuery - but knowing more detail about the data etc. may lead to a better solution overall.

Comment: Answers in this post will help you if you cannot fix the data... and you can use JQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6976452/4646537

Comment: This is what I have written and it is not working

var A = this.getField("Pump.0").value;
var B = this.getField("Pump.1").value;
var C = this.getField("SN 2.0").value;

if(B !== A && A !== "" && B !== ""){if(B === A){event.value = "";}else{event.value = C;}}